# Use of quotation marks

Tags: javascript, css

Why does this line of code produce the desired results:

```
document.getElementById('ID').style.backgroundImage = 'url('+ variable +')';
```

While this line does not:

```
document.getElementById('ID').style.backgroundImage = "url('+ variable +')";
```

How do I use quotes in `JavaScript`?

Comment: because `"` and `'` are treated differently in javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript the single and double quote marks are interchangeable but must be using in matching pairs. If your text already contains one style, you can use the other style to preserve the one you want to use as part of the text. So suppose `variable = "mypage"` then

```
'url('+ variable +')'
```

will encode a string as

> url(mypage)

But

```
"url('+ variable +')"
```

will encode this literally, operators, variable name and all

> url('+ variable +')

An example of where you might want to do this is

```
myname = "John";
sentence = 'My name is "' + myname + '".';
```

which will give

> My name is "John".